# LateInitializationError: Field 'productItem' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I am building a flutter app and I am getting a LateInitialization error on the productItem field. I made an instance of the ProductItem class so that I could access and pass the instance variables to my methods in the ProductItemState class. I also tried making the field nullable but I then ended up getting a "unexpect null value" error. I'm not sure which other way I can access those instance variables in my ProductItemState class. Please can anyone kindly assist.

```
class ProductItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  String bottleName;
  String imgUrl;
  double price;
  Bottle bottle;
  ProductItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.id,
      required this.bottleName,
      required this.imgUrl,
      required this.price,
      required this.bottle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductItem> createState() => _ProductItemState();
}

class _ProductItemState extends State<ProductItem>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
    late ProductItem productItem;
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    var cart = Provider.of<ShoppingCartProvider>(context);
    var favoriteProvider = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context);
    return Card(
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.amber,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                favoriteProvider.toggleFavorites(productItem.bottle);
                if (favoriteProvider.isExist(productItem.bottle)) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Product Added to Favorite!",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Product Removed from Favorite!",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: favoriteProvider.isExist(productItem.bottle)
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    )
                  : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  productItem.imgUrl,
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Text(productItem.bottleName,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              Center(
                child: Text('R${productItem.price}'),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 10,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                iconSize: 40.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  cart.addToCart(productItem.id, productItem.bottleName,
                      productItem.price, productItem.imgUrl);
                },
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*late* means you are telling Flutter that i will make sure that this field gets initialized, don't do null checks on this variable. But you are using late and not initializing productItem, which is resulting in runtime error

Answer (score 1):

You need to start productItem variable. When you use **late**, you guarantee that you will start right after this variable.

Use

```
Product product = Product(id, name);
```

Instead of

```
late Product product;
```

or

```
late Product product;
product = Product(id, name);
```

**Edit:**

I'm adding below the code I put in the comment link of this answer and which @Anesu said worked.

```
class ProductItem {
  String id;
  String bottleName;
  String imgUrl;
  String price;
  Bottle bottle;

  ProductItem({required this.id, required this.bottleName, required this.imgUrl, required this.price});
}

class ProductItemPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductItem item;
  
  ProductItemPage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.item})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductItemPage> createState() => _ProductItemPageState();
}

class _ProductItemPageState extends State<ProductItemPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  
   late ProductItem productItem;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    productItem = widget.item;
  }
  
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    var cart = Provider.of<ShoppingCartProvider>(context);
    var favoriteProvider = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context);
    return Card(
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.amber,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                favoriteProvider.toggleFavorites(productItem.bottle);
                if (favoriteProvider.isExist(productItem.bottle)) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Product Added to Favorite!",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Product Removed from Favorite!",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: favoriteProvider.isExist(productItem.bottle)
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    )
                  : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  productItem.imgUrl,
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Text(productItem.bottle,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              Center(
                child: Text('R${productItem.price}'),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 10,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                iconSize: 40.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  cart.addToCart(productItem.id, productItem.bottleName,
                      productItem.price, productItem.imgUrl);
                },
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I initialize this productItem variable it will reassign new values to the constructor and replace the passed values. So the output will now be wrong values

Comment: How are you initializing the variable?

Comment: I just put in default values like this  ProductItem productItem = ProductItem(
      id: '"",
      bottleName: "",
      imgUrl: "",
      price: 0.0,
      bottle: Bottle(
          id: "",
          bottleName: '"",
          image: "",
          bottletype: "",
          time: 0,
          price: 0.0));

Comment: I believe you need to create another class to assign this data. Try doing like [in this example](https://codeshare.io/DZmlOW). If it works, let me know so I can edit the code above and you can mark it as solved.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! I don't know why I didn't think about using widget to invoke the passed variables :)

Comment: I'm happy about it! I edited the answer and posted the code for others to see in the future.